# Как изменить div лежащий в одном блоке с другим div через :hover

Tags: css, hover

Такой код

```html
<div class="block">
    <div class="elem-x">
    <div class="elem-y">
    <div class="elem-z">
</div>
```

Мне нужно чтобы при наведении на elem-x менялось свойство elem-z

Знаю что таким образом   .block1:hover ~ .block2 h1 { color: red;} можно изменять даже элементы другого дива, но как изменять сам div не знаю.

Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почему только элементы? Сам блок можно менять тоже:

```css
.elem-x:hover ~ .elem-z { background-color: red;}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="elem-x">x</div>
  <div class="elem-y">y</div>
  <div class="elem-z">z</div>
</div>
```

Или Вы что-то другое имели в виду?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но у меня почему-то не работает. Буду искать ошибку.

Comment: @НайтПавел, нужно, чтобы блоки лежали на одном уровне и блок с ховером шёл раньше, чем изменяемый блок (потому что стили идут каскадом - сверху вниз). Возможно, какое-то условие у Вас не соблюдается. Либо банально опечатка в селекторах